# Getting actual field value inside replace(function() {}) in RethinkDB

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

I am stuck trying to update to all entries I have saved in a RethinkDB table. Basically, I am trying to loop over all entries, read a property and save the processed result back to the same document as a new property.

I am using `replace(function(entry) { return <object>})` as the key conversion piece.

Inside the replace function, `entry.getField('fieldname')` *returns a function, not my stored value* and this is where everything goes wrong.

*What is the appropriate way to get the actual value from the document?*

**These lines from the function passed to `replace` is where it goes wrong**

```
var ts = entry.getField('timestamp'); // Debugger says 'ts' is a Function!
var date = new Date(ts); // Fails because Date expects a string
```

**The Full Code**

```
/* Steps
 * 1 - Select all entries in DB.
 * 2 - For each entry
 *  2.1 - Read existing property 'timestamp' (format: '2015-05-06 15:04:48')
 *  2.2 - Convert to rethinkDB format and assign to new property 'timestampraw'
 *  2.3 - Replace entry
 */

var migrateDb = function migrateDb(r, conn, dbName, tableName) {
    r.db(dbName).table(tableName).limit(2)
        .replace(function (entry) {
            var ts = entry.getField('timestamp'); // 'ts' is a Function!?
            var date = new Date(ts); // This fails, because we are not passing in the actual property value
            entry.timestampraw = r.ISO8601(date, {defaultTimezone: '+02'});
            entry.converted = true;
            return entry;
        })
        .run(conn, {useOutdated: true, arrayLimit: 1000000}, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            log(util.inspect(res));
        });
};


var r = require('rethinkdb');
r.connect(conf).then(function (conn) {
    migrateDb(r, conn, conf.db, conf.tableName);
});
```

**Example data from the database**

```
[{ id: '000264a9-63a3-4e8e-90b7-b1c256d79be3',
  name: 'waterLevel',
  timestamp: '2015-04-30 10:47:44',
  unit: 'cm',
  value: '14.1' 
},
{ id: '0000b44f-5754-498b-ba65-c79660f34618',
  name: 'pumpCurrent',
  raw: '-224',
  timestamp: '2015-05-06 15:04:48',
  unit: 'mA',
  value: 0
 }]
```

I have close to 500 000 values in the table, so that's why you see the limit() clause in the code example. Just want to experiment using a small subset.

I am using RethinkDB v2.0.1 from Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're getting that that value is a function, but I don't think you can just run JavaScript inside the function. Keep in mind that in `entry` inside the `replace` function is not an JS object. It's a ReQL object.

How about trying the following:

```
var migrateDb = function migrateDb(r, conn, dbName, tableName) {
    r.db(dbName).table(tableName).limit(2)
        .replace(function (entry) {
            return entry.merge({
                // This is a way to get around ISO8601 date parsing
                // We're basically replacing a ' ' with 'T'
                'timestampraw' : r.ISO8601(
                    entry('timestamp').split()(0).add('T').add(entry('timestamp').split()(1)), 
                    {defaultTimezone: '+2' 
                }),
                'converted': true
            });
        })
        .run(conn, {useOutdated: true, arrayLimit: 1000000}, function (err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            log(util.inspect(res));
        });
};
```

Comment: That did the trick! The documentation for RethinkDB is generally quite good, but it skips over some of the very fundamental parts I feel. One example is the API of and a description of ReQL-objects. Do you happen to have a pointer where I can read more? Also, is there any documentation on what is allowed inside a function passed to replace(), or map() or forEach(). It is very much a guessing game.

Comment: This might be a good reference although it's a bit advanced: http://rethinkdb.com/blog/lambda-functions/

Comment: If this answered your question, make sure to mark it as "answered" for future reference. Thanks!